# internet availability notification .net vs native (c++)

Tags: c++, .net, performance, connection, ping

My .net application (client-server) that needs to known immediately when the server (ping an url) is back online, and the only way i see it is to do ping it every 10/50/100 ms.

The client application is running on Kiosks with average-to-low performance PCs, in order to optimize this and I am thinking of writing a separate native application that would be in charge of ping-ing the server heartbeat address.

My question is would implementing it in C++ make any performance difference than just creating simple .net application ?

Comment: No, sending a small request to ping a server is a very light-weight operation.

Comment: Network latency vs CPU speed. Which one is faster?

Comment: Ok, but now imagine a 10 ms retry interval.

Comment: @Zapacila do you really want to check the internet connection every 10ms?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, it wouldn't make any difference as the most "expensive" part is waiting for response. You can check it very simple using this code:

```
try
{
    System.Net.IPHostEntry objIPHE = System.Net.Dns.GetHostEntry("www.google.com");
}
catch
{
   MessageBox.Show("No internet");
}
```

Comment: I don't know much about .net programming, but wouldn't that also "work" if the ip is somehow cached (either locally, or by a dns within the local network)?

Comment: @PlasmaHH the GetHostEntry method will issue the request anyway

Comment: DNS lookup is irrelevant, want i'm looking is basically which would be faster, c++ socket api vs .net socket and if there is big difference in performance

Comment: @Zapacila: My guess would be that writing some test code would have been faster than to ask the question here...

Comment: @Zapacila querying dns is less expensive than ping as ping will do the dns lookup in most cases anyway